# A PROBLEM WITH XML Standard Layer Descriptor for GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, sld, xml, color

I wrote an xml in Standard Layer Descriptor for GeoServer, with the objective to map a satellite image with discrete values. I wrote:

```
< ColorMap type="intervals">
  < ColorMapEntry color="#000000" quantity="0" label="b"/>  
  < ColorMapEntry color="#00FF00" quantity="10" label="c"/>
  < ColorMapEntry color="#FFFF00" quantity="20" label="d"/> 
< /ColorMap>
```

The problem is that a value corresponds to a color set in a previous line, for example the pixel value 10 corresponds to #000000 color (but this color has to corresponds to value 0.)

Answer (score 1):

The bounds in the interval are not inclusive below but are inclusive above.

You are coloring values <0 to #0000000; values >=0 && < 10 to #00FF00; values >=10 && <20 to #ffff00.

See this [cookbook](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/rasters.html#id10) example for details.